# Get World-Position from Transform-Hierarchy with Quaternions

Tags: c++, graphics

i am programming a rendering engine and i'm looking for a nice way to calculate the world position of my objects.
Currently i do this:

```
Point3f Node::getWorldPosition()
{
   // Return the translation-component of the world matrix as a Point3f
   return getWorldMatrix().getTranslation(); 
}
```

with

```
Mat4f Node::getWorldMatrix()
{
    if (parent == nullptr) //reached root node
        return transform.getTransformationMatrix();

    return parent->getWorldMatrix() * transform.getTransformationMatrix();
}
```

This works fine, but i try to find a solution without calculating the gigantic transformation matrix. First i had this

```
Point3f Node::getWorldPosition()
{
    if (parent == nullptr) //reached root node
        return transform.position;

    return parent->getWorldPosition() * transform.position;
}
```

But of course i forgot to take the rotation into account and i dont know how i can achieve this. I am using quaternions for the rotations.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a solution without calculating the gigantic transformation matrix

There isn't one.

The absolute best you're ever going to get is caching matrices. That is, keep the world matrices you generate for each node, until something changes in that node or a parent that invalidates it. But such code can be difficult and fragile, as many operations can invalidate a cached matrix. Keeping track of such things can be difficult.

There's no magic solution that will allow you to generate world-space information without actually *generating world-space*. Even if you knew that node transformations only involve translation followed by rotation, you still have to accumulate all of those rotations and translations. And that's the lion's share of the work; whatever minor performance you might save from not using matrices will be exactly that: minor.